# While using the AChartEngine, some labels in X-axis get garbled (messed) up

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using the AChartEngine library to display a line chart in my app. Unfortunately some of the x-axis label get garbled up.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are displaying both the default labels and your custom labels. In order to hide the default labels, please call:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
```